# How to right-align the TinyMCE browser itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, activeadmin

I have integrated a tinymce editor in a rails project with active admin.

I spent almost a couple of hours looking for a way to align the editor to the right of my available space, as currently it's hiding the labels for it.

I have the following init js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  tinyMCE.init({
     mode: 'textareas',
     align: 'right',
     width: '80%',
     height: 200,
     autoresize_min_height: 200, 
     autoresize_max_height: 400,
     resize: 'both',
     plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview'
   });
});
```

Read much of the TinyMCE4 documentation and couldn't find a way to align the window to the right. My attempts to override the css class for this are as well no successful.

Could you please give me an advice. Does someone know how to deal with the alignment via the js init?

Here's the screenshot: http://betasve.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/TinymceProblemAA.png

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you insert a screenshot?

Comment: I tried but it says I lack the rating needed for uploading a screenshot. I will upload it to some site and link it here (in the article).

Comment: In your Gemfile, which version of activeadmin and tinymce-rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in active_admin.css.scss:

```
.mce-tinymce {
  margin-left: 215px !important;
+
```

Comment: Thanks, that one worked perfectly! I've tried with !important myself, but I probably did it in the wrong css file.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer make by nistvan, works better with:

```
.mce-tinymce { margin-left: 20% !important;}
```